# How to remove popup blocker in address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have written this code on button click event. But at run time, popup blocked message occurs.

How can I remove that popup blocker through this code?

```
protected void btnExamOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string queryString = "StudentTextTest1.aspx?TestId=" + ddlTest.SelectedValue;
     string jquery = "window.open('" + queryString + "');";
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", jquery, true);
}
```

Comment: You realise that a popup blocker is browser specific, and you can't do anything about it? Otherwise, there would be no point in having the blocker in the first place?

Comment: The user needs to allow popups on your site. This is a browser setting. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Ok, I will do that browser setting but user cannot be...So,what can be done?

Comment: I dont think there is a way to disable it using your code because it is browser specific..Change your approach is my advise..

Comment: You could create a modal dialog containing an iframe instead of opening a new browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way most popup blockers work is that they block all automatic popups.

It generally accepts popups that are opened by user action, like on a click event. My guess is that RegisterStartupScript doesn't call the javascript directly.

If possible, move the code to a client side Javascript file.